# get result from leanback activity

Tags: android, android-activity, television, leanback

I have a Main activity activity and this starts the leanbackactivity with startactivityforresult. The problem is onActivityResult never gets called.
Code from leanbackactivity:

```
Intent data = getIntent();
data.putExtra("url", url);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

and code from mainactivity

```
Intent landingIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LeanbackActivity.class);
landingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivityForResult(landingIntent, 1);
```

and result code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is no problem.

Are there fragment in Activiy?
if have ,you should try `getActivity.startActivityForResult(landingIntent, 1);` in your fragment.